# Is there a list of deprecated Viewhelpers in Fluid?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

I got an extension that provides a lot of custom content elements. The extension was developed for TYPO3 v7. Now it should be used for TYPO3 10. Since there is a higher fluid version now, I would like to know if there is a list of deprecated viewhelpers because I want to update those templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `10.x` instance login to the Backend as full admin and maintainer, go to:

- Admin Tool

  - Upgrade

    - Scan Extension Files

There find the extension you are working on and scan it, it should show you deprecated methods, annotations, etc. Also with documentation on how to fix it.

[image: Scan your code]

Other approach I'd would check. It's common by the core team to annotate depracated classes, methods and others with similar annotation:

ie. for **typo3/sysext/setup/Classes/Controller/SetupModuleController.php -> simulateUser() method** in ver `9.x`

```
@deprecated since TYPO3 v9, will be removed in TYPO3 v10.0.
```

or **typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Widget/AutocompleteViewHelper.php** ViewHelper in ver.: `10.x`

```
@deprecated since TYPO3 v10.4, will be removed in TYPO3 v11.0.
```

So you can use your IDE to search for all occurences of `@deprecated since` string.

Comment: Thank you for this! I think this could be really helpful. Unfortunately this shows that there are no critical code lines. This is weird because I'm sure that some things don't work because some Templates are being display in the backend and some aren't.

Comment: It's quite possible, that it doesn't perform checks for too old versions (sorry just guessing) in general, when updating from _a.x_ to _n.x_ it's always suggested to do it version by version and resolving all problems at each step. Sometimes moving from 7.x to 10.x at once can be problematic.

Comment: I didn't move from 7 to 10 in one step. I did it LTS per LTS but just didn't fix the frontend, only the backend.

Comment: That's the correct way, anyway, success is never guaranteed, unfortunately. BTW what is deprecated ViewHelper in your case?

Comment: What do you mean? I am looking for some tags (like i.e. <flux:grid.column></flux:grid.column>) that got removed in the newer versions of fluid/flux and cause errors now.

Comment: So actually it's not the case of the TYPO3 core, but third-part extensions which should be updated if available for 10.x. Did you updated to the newest version: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/flux/